# Do we want to allow historical legal questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, something about the effects of [Quia Emptores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quia_Emptores) or the [Statute of Uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_of_Uses) and how they relate to modern property/trust law.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely.  Practical law is informed not only by statute but also by "common law," which is informed by historical custom as well as judicial precedents.  As an example of how far back a court may reach for precedent consider the [Canadian Supreme Court's 2002 ruling in *Whiten v. Pilot Insurance Co.*](http://www.canlii.org/en/ca/scc/doc/2002/2002scc18/2002scc18.html) in which (41) they cite practices from the second millennium *B.C.*!